# php traverse object using variables for property names

Tags: php, json, object

I have a case where I may recive one of two json objects, in this case from either the google geocode api, or the places api.

Acccessing values from the geocoding api it will look like this:

```
$coordinates            = $data->results[0]->geometry->location;
$cache_value['lat'] = (string) $coordinates->lat;
$cache_value['lng'] = (string) $coordinates->lng;
```

and an almost identical structure for places.

```
$coordinates            = $data->result->geometry->location;
$cache_value['lat'] = (string) $coordinates->lat;
$cache_value['lng'] = (string) $coordinates->lng;
```

In my code I've two functions to handle each case, but they are almost idential with the exception of the `result` vs `results[0]` and I'd like to combine them. I've tried to passing a varriable but it throws errors:

```
$result         = ($place) ? 'result' : 'results[0]';
$coordinates    = $data->$result->geometry->location;
```

Gives the following:

**Notice**`: Undefined property: stdClass::$result[0]`

I'd like to know the correct syntax to achive what im after, and any pointers on nominclature, as Im afraid this question title is a bit inpercise.

Comment: Is that missing quote on `'results[0];` a typo?

Comment: why not just 
   $result = ($place) ? $data->result : $data->results[0]; and then $coordinates = $result->geometry->location;

Comment: @RUJordan, yup that's been corrected now - thanks

Comment: @stakolee - thats a good point, I'll chew on that one.

Comment: @stakolee - btw, nice missippi john hurt / SO conflation there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$result         = $place ? $data->result : $data->results[0];
$coordinates    = $result->geometry->location;
```

What your code is doing, is this: It tries to resolve a property of `$data` object with a **name** of `results[0]`, and there is none; Once again - it does not resolve `0` index of the `results` property, but it tries to find a property with a literal name `results[0]`; It would work if your object looked like this:

```
$obj = (object)array( 'results[0]' => 'hey there' );
```

If for any reason you would like to play with that, you could create a silly property like this: `$data->{'results[0]'} = 5;` - but it's stupid, don't do that :)

Comment: +1 for the extra explanation as to what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

i believe php is looking for a key named `results[0]`, its not smart enough to know that the properties name is `results` and you want the first member of the collection `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the reference of the variable name, rather than its value.

```
$result = ($place) ? 'result' : 'results[0]';
$coordinates = $data->$result->geometry->location;
```

`$result` is just a string and should be the actual value of either `$data->result` or `$data->result[0]`.

To correct it, simply use `$result` to hold the value of result.

```
$result = ($place) ? $data->result : $data->results[0];
$coordinates = $result->geometry->location;
```